# What should I do if a valve won't shut off the water?

Tags: water

My garage spigot was attached by a thin PVC pipe, and broke off in the cold. I knew right where the inside gate to shut it off was, from when I had an issue with it before. I even had it labeled. I turned and turned and turned, and it just wouldn't shut off the water, so I had to close the main feed from my well-holding tank.

I saw a comment from you all that says if it's in a horizontal run (it is), it could gather sediment and not want to seat properly? My other choice is to cap off the PVC, but it's a small nub that's left. Ideas?

Comment: You eventually need to fix that gate valve, but a cap seems like the best bet for the short term.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Right, on replacing gate. A job for another, warmer day. I got a no-glue end cap, but was skeptical. Sure enough, it was still dripping some. My son had some marine epoxy, so I plugeed the end with it, and sealed the first joint that was also dripping. Dripping stopped, and I put a heater blowing on it in the garage because it's 18 degrees today.